# Regular expression help

Tags: regex

The strings to be matched are based on length. 
String ***S*** should be matched iff ***(|S| mod 3) > (|S| mod 2)*** 
where **|S|** is the length of the string.

I've tried to find wrt LCM but I don't know how to proceed with the solution.

The length that can be accepted is 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, ...
How to build this regex.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let the strings consist of lowercase alphabets for simplicity, so `[a-z]` is one character

The accepted lengths are a sequence 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 20, 22, ...
We can group these as {2}, {4,5,8}, {10,11,14}, {16,17,20}, ...

Notice that 4 on the addition of 6 gives 10, 5 on the addition of 6 gives 11, and so on.

To build the regex, consider the special cases first:
      length of 2, regex would be `[a-z]{2}`
      similarly for lengths 4, 5 and 8  regex would be `[a-z]{4}`, `[a-z]{5}`, `[a-z]{8}`

For lengths greater than 8, zero or more, six-character string is appended
so the final regex would be

```
[a-z]{2} + ( [a-z]{4} )( [a-z]{6} )* + ( [a-z]{5} )( [a-z]{6} )* + ( [a-z]{8} )( [a-z]{6} )*
```

Comment: Please use the { } icon above the edit window to format lines as code.